# CodeIgniter - Loading View inside subfolder showing 404

Tags: php, codeigniter

Trying to load a view from a subfolder the path is like:

(views/pages/users/test.php)

Below is my `Pages.php file`

```
<?php
    class Pages extends CI_Controller{
        public function view($page = '/') {
            if(!file_exists(APPPATH.'views/pages/'.$page.'.php')) {
                show_404();
            }

            $data['title'] = ucfirst($page);

            $this->load->view('templates/header');
            $this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        }

    }
```

I already tried with controller and changed my code but still I am not able to view the page test.php which is inside the folder view/pages/users/test.php

PFB **tried code**:-

```
public function subview($page = '/') {
            if(!file_exists(APPPATH.'views/pages/users'.$page.'.php')) {
                show_404();
            }

            $data['title'] = ucfirst($page);

            $this->load->view('templates/header');
            $this->load->view('pages/users'.$page, $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        }
```

**Getting error message**:-

> 404 Page Not Found The page you requested was not found.

Comment: $this->load->view('pages/users/'.$page, $data); add forward slash after users folder. also in  if(!file_exists(APPPATH.'views/pages/users/'.$page.'.php')) {
                show_404();
            }

Answer (score 0):

First you will need to fix your `if` statement at the top to reflect the correct path:

```
if(!file_exists(APPPATH.'views/pages/users/'.$page.'.php')) {
     show_404();
}
```

And then fix the load call like so:

```
$this->load->view('pages/users/'.$page, $data);
```

The problem is, you didn't add the `/` after the `users` in your path so the file can't be found and will always show 404 because of it.

I just set up a test project to demonstrate this code:

[image]

Then in the `Welcome.php` controller I created a `testSubView` function which looks like this:

```php
function testSubView($page = ""){
    if(!file_exists(APPPATH. "views/pages/users/{$page}.php")) {
        show_404();
    }

    echo "The file {$page}.php exists<br/>";

    echo "Loading the file pages/users/{$page}.php ...<br/><br/>";

    $this->load->view("pages/users/$page");
}
```

**Test.php file contents:**

```
<?php
echo "This is content from test.php file";
```

So when I visit my apps url: `localhost/app/index.php/welcome/testSubView/test` 
I will get this output:

> The file test.php exists
>
> Loading the file pages/users/test.php ...
>
> This is content from test.php file

To explain the demo url a bit:

- welcome - Is the name of a controller file
- testSubView - Is the name of a function inside of the controller file
- test - Is the name of the view file I'm loading inside of the function

Comment: I have several projects that use sub folders to organize view files. And they all work like I suggested there. But I will try and update my answer to give you more examples

Comment: Thanks for reply, But still I am getting the same error, do you have any sample project where you use subfolder to view the pages, As this is very big project I want to use subfolder to separate the code for future use. My folder structure is (views->pages) inside pages folder I have my index.php, signin.php and so on and it is running fine on the browser side, but once I create a subfolder inside pages folder (views->pages->users) and try to create a test.php file inside users folder to test whether it is running fine or not on browser, it start showing error. Error I mention below.

Comment: Are you sure you are passing the `$page` variable to the function inside of your controller ? You can add test `var_dump($page); return false;` before your `if` check to see if your are receiving the `$page` variable and what value are you getting from it.

Comment: Dear Igor, I was created a separate controller to handle my routing part, Above I mention my Controller, Please look, Pages.php

Comment: This code should work without a problem in any controller. I used `Welcome.php` as it was already there and just for an example. Can you print out the value of the `$page` variable and post it here so that we can see what you are getting as a value in there ?

Comment: Dear Igor, Yes the file is start running, The value I am getting is The file test.php exists
Loading the file pages/users/test.php ...

This is content from test.php file

Comment: Dear Igor above code is working fine with Welcome.php, But my routing is working through Pages.php created manually which is mention above.                                         So how I will proceed, I will proceed with Welcome.php or some changes need to be done in Pages.php to get the work done.

Comment: Like I mentioned before it doesn't matter in which controller you place the code it will work. You just need to fix the errors outline in the answer above in your code and everything should work. In your `subview` function in your `Pages` controller